# Create an increasing integer alternating sequence in MATLAB / Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, numerical-methods, numerical

I'm trying to find a way to create a number pattern like the one below

`0,1,-2,3,-4,5`....

*Please note: it needs to go to 200000, but I will be splitting them up into groups of 2000*.

I found a formula that looks like it would work on http://oeis.org/A181983, but when I create the formula in MATLAB / Octave, the numbers don't match up:

```
f_num= @(x) x / (1 + x)^2;
numval = f_num(1)
numval =  0.25000
```

Is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: That sequence is a divergent harmonic series.  There is no closed form formula that will give you that answer.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for the clarification I was wondering why it wasn't working

Comment: No problem :) I've added a couple more methods to produce this alternating series for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Method #1 - Using `(-1)^x`

Just use a linear increment operator to go from `0` to `200000` and multiply the sequence by `(-1)^(x+1)` to allow the sign of the sequence to alternate:

```
x = 0:200000;
y = ((-1).^(x+1)) .* x;
```

The addition of the `+1` is important so that the even positions get a positive sign while the odd positions get a negative sign.

## Method #2 - Using indexing

Alternatively, you can declare the same array from `0` to `200000`, index into every even position and negate the sign:

```
x = 0:200000;
x(2:2:end) = -x(2:2:end);
```

## Method #3 - Using trigonometry and integers

One more to throw into the mix.  You know that for `cos(x*pi)`, the output is -1 when `x` is odd and the output is 1 when `x` is even.  We need to flip this for your case and ultimately use this alternating sequence to multiply with the same array going from `0` to `200000`, and therefore:

```
x = 0:200000;
y = (-cos(x*pi)).*x;
```

## Aside

Interestingly enough, `(-1)^x` is also equal to `exp(i*pi*x)` for all values of `x` that are integer.  We can verify this by using Euler's formula where: `exp(i*pi*x) = cos(pi*x) + i*sin(pi*x)`.  Since `i*sin(pi*x) = 0` for all `x` belonging to an integer, we really get `exp(i*pi*x) = cos(pi*x)`.  Substituting even numbers of `x` will give us 1 while odd numbers of `x` will give us -1, and hence `exp(i*pi*x) = cos(pi*x) = (-1)^x` for all `x` belonging to integers.

Also, `(-1)^(x+1) = -(-1)^x = -cos(x*pi)` for all `x` belonging to integers and so the first method is really equal to the third method anyway!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
f_num= @(x) x * (-1)^(x+1);
```